# Not the easiest merge in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I think in my last attempts I explained too complicated, so I try to cut my problems a bit smaller.

I am looking for a solution to the following problem. I have two dataframes and want to get the result from the dataframe "df_result" at the end.

```
df_1 = data.frame(id=c(1, 15, 14, 35, 19, 19, 36, 18, 57, 78, 94), year=c(2018, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2020, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2018))
```

[image]

```
df_2 = data.frame(id=c(1, 15, 15, 14, 35, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 36, 18, 57, 78, 94), year=c(2018, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2020, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2018), color=c("green", "blue", "yellow", "green", "red", "black", "white", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "white", "blue", "green"), weight=c(NA, 2, 1, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

[image]

```
df_result = data.frame(id=c(1, 15, 14, 35, 19, 19, 36, 18, 57, 78, 94), year=c(2018, 2020, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2020, 2017, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2018), result=c("green", "yellow", "green", "red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "yellow", "white", "blue", "green"))
```

[image]

Information:

- As you can see in df_1, each id has at least one year. For example, id 19 has 2 years (2018, 2020).
- df_2 has at least 1 entry for each id with a matching year. If there are several entries, "weight" indicates which entry has priority (1 means highest priority).
- In df_result there is then only the color whose weight from df_2 has the smallest number.

I know how I can find the problem cases, but what are the next steps?

```
df_temp <- df_2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n() >= 2)
view(df_temp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `df_2` by `df_1` and select 1st row after arranging the data by weight.

```
library(dplyr)

df_2 %>%
  left_join(df_1, by = c('id', 'year')) %>%
  arrange(id, weight) %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  slice(1L) %>%
  dplyr::select(-weight) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 11 x 3
#      id  year color 
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1     1  2018 green 
# 2    14  2019 green 
# 3    15  2020 yellow
# 4    18  2019 yellow
# 5    19  2018 orange
# 6    19  2020 yellow
# 7    35  2020 red   
# 8    36  2017 blue  
# 9    57  2020 white 
#10    78  2019 blue  
#11    94  2018 green
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this in the right dataframes right away.

Another thing that came to my mind: my df_2 also contains ids that are not contained in df_1. These must not appear in the results.

Comment: You could change `left_join` to `inner_join` to include only the id's that appear in both of them.